# Executing raw SQL queries with EF Core and SQL Server - System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Could not find stored procedure 'Core.SetContextInfo'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I use EF Core 7 in an ASP.NET Core project. EF Core's `FromSql` method thinks the provided parameter is the name for a stored procedure, when it's an actual SQL query. How can I make it run select queries and retrieve results?

Based on the [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries), I need to use either `FromSql` or `FromSqlInterpolated` methods to perform `SELECT` operations with raw SQL input. However, when I use `FromSql`, I get the error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT * FROM dbo.Country'

This simple test query (`SELECT * FROM dbo.Country`) works fine when I run it in SSMS. However, for some reason, EF Core thinks it is the name for a stored procedure, and attempts to find a stored procedure, which obviously fails.

I tried to see if `FromSql` method has an overload for specifying whether the string parameter is an actual query or the name for a stored procedure, but it doesn't seem to be a possibility. It looks like the method only takes in a single string parameter, and somehow makes a decision inside on whether the provided parameter is a stored procedure or a query.

On the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries), it is clear that `FromSql` is capable of taking actual queries as input.

Here is my code where I'm getting the error (parameter is `SELECT * FROM dbo.Country`):

```
public async Task<List<T>> RunRawSql(string query)
{
    try
    {
        var a = _context.Set<T>().FromSql($"{query}");
        return a.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DaleK I made it a bit shorter. I solved the problem by the way.

Comment: @DaleK yup, done. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `FromSql` method does not allow parameterizing actual database schema (table names, column names, etc). In my case, I am sending the whole query as a parameter, which falls into the category of parameterizing database schema, thus `FromSql` does not work. Apparently, if you need to parameterize schema, you must use `FromSqlRaw` instead.

Note that `FromSqlRaw` is prone to SQL injection attacks, so you should instead use `FromSql` or `FromSqlInterpolated` whenever possible. You must pay attention to never send any user input into here. However, as long as you completely decouple this method from any user input, it is okay to use `FromSqlRaw`.

Comment: "that FromSql method does not allow parameterizing actual database schema" this is an SQL issue in general: you cannot parameterize the shape of the query (like object and column names), only its variables.